# How can I change ViewController with tapping an UIImageView?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, touch, viewcontroller

I created a CollectionView. This view has a userProfileImageView and I want to change view controller to ProfilePage when clicked this user profile image. Try some code but neither present nor push view controller doesn't work to me. Can you help me ?

```
 lazy var userProfileImageView: UIImageView = {

    let useriv = UIImageView()
    useriv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    useriv.clipsToBounds = true
    useriv.layer.cornerRadius = 40 / 2
    useriv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    useriv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userImageTap)))
    return useriv

}()

@objc func userImageTap() {

    print("useriv clicked")
    let profilePage = ProfilePage(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())



}
```

Comment: you have to present the `profilePage` somewhere

Comment: yeah I tried this present in userImageTap() but it doesn't work

Comment: Value of type 'HomePostCell' has no member 'present' this warning

Comment: not clear what you mean. You can present from UIViewController, or UICollectionViewController, etc.